# Infinity norm of identity function

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to use Holder's extremal equality

$$
\|x||_{\infty} = \sup_{f \in L^{1}, \|f\|= 1}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |xf(x)|
$$
to compute the right side of this equation.

Cleary $\|x||_{\infty} = b$ when defined on a bounded interval $[a,b]$ but on all of $\mathbb{R}$ this is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $+\infty$. The function $f(x)$ equal to $1$ on $[n, n+1]$ and $0$ elsewhere is $L_1$, and the integral is at least $n$ for that function.

Comment: Do you know what happens in the case of f is a smooth function with compact support, or the case f in a dense set of L^p

Comment: @jacobi2953 That's not the problem. You can still make $f$ be concentrated on $[n, n+1]$ to make the integral large. Your integral is essentially the expected value of a random variable, with $f$ acting as the probability density function. The "smoothness" of the probability distribution is not the issue, it's the unboundedness of it.